# Why need to add an OAuth 2.0 for Azure service that is already protected by Azure AD

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

**Backgournd:**

Our group using Azure AD to authenticate and authorise the resources that belongs to us in Azure. AKA, you need to login by your working ID to get verified it is a person belong to our group. This is how a team member can use the API service we owned.

**Issue:**

There is suggestion that to add an OAuth 2.0 authorization on top of the API. I get confused here. It is only used internally and protected by Azure AD. And login by Azure AD isn't itself already some kind of OAuth 2.0 authentication?

Comment: If your data is sensitive, such as private user data, then you need to put some sort of security layer on your API. Also, using OAuth or other token based security can help you build a better permission checking across your user base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the API does not have any protection, that means that anyone can hit the endpoint and get the information from the api. for example, if some random person with a cell phone connected to your wifi network somehow or hardwire laptop, they could query the api directly if there was no authentication/authorization on the endpoint. or if its on azure functions or something, then most likely anyone can access it on the internet.

I'm curious on what you mean by the resources are protected by azure ad. Where exactly did you set this up? if for example you are using an azure function as an api endpoint and you activated azure ad authentication/authorization on the azure function app, then your api layer IS secured and you can access the user tokens in the code. in this case there is nothing further to do.